# How to formulate the sum of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

When presented with a sequence of the form:

$a_0 = 1$

$a_{n+1} = b a_n + c a_{n-1}$

I know that I can compute the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ item by using matrix multiplication. I don't recall the method used to compute the sum of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_n$ be the sum of the first $n$ values of $a_i$ . The recurrence matrix will be:

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
b & c & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0  \\
b & c & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix}$

It satisfies $A\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\a_{n-1} \\s_n \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1} \\a_{n} \\s_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}$

Hence $A^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\a_0 \\s_1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\a_{n-1} \\s_n \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence is solved from the roots of the characteristic polynomial

$$r^2=br+c.$$

The latter is quadratic, so that the general solution is

$$a_n=pr_0^{n}+qr_1^n$$ where the constants $p,q$ are determined from the initial conditions.

You easily deduce

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_n=p\frac{r_0^{n+1}-1}{r_0-1}+q\frac{r_1^{n+1}-1}{r_1-1}.$$

Comment: I think op wants matrix multiplcation to be able to do binary exponentiation without needing floating point precision

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: matrix multiplication does not address the precision issue. Whatever the approach, the final value is the same.

Comment: I meant $r_0$ and $r_1$.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to work around it, but sometimes $r_0$ and $r_1$ are not integers, and this could potentially lead to round-off errors. Maybe there are smart ways to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the general term first. Ansatz $a_n = x^n$ we have $x^2 - b x - c$. The solutions are given by
$$x_{\pm} = \frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2+4c}}{2}$$
and so we have $a_n = c_+ x_+^n + c_- x_-^n$ with $c_+ + c_- = 1$ (the initial value term $a_0$). Then the formula for a geometric series should easily yield the result.